# Python: Read URLs from csv/Excel column

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, request

The last column of my Excel file is filled with url links. I want to read text from these urls, so that I can search key words in the text. The problem is that requests.get cannot read a column of urls. Can you help me on this? Thank you!!!

My current code is here:

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_excel('/Users/LE/Downloads/url.xlsx')
url=data.URL
res=requests.get(url, headers=headers)
html=res.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

It cannot work because 'url' is a column.

[image: CompleteExcel]

Comment: you need to read the excel file first by pandas by example and iterate through the last column, to get more help share the structure of your Excel file and its name.

Comment: Thank you so much Hanna! I have updated my picture, hope you can see it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did great with opening the file and extracting the column with the urls,

one last step is to loop through them - repeat the request for each url in the urls -

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# open the file
data = pd.read_excel('/Users/LE/Downloads/url.xlsx')

# get the urls
urls = data.URL

# go through every url in the urls
for url in urls:

    # do the request for this url
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    # soup-it
    html = res.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, this line will give you the entire column:

```
url=data.URL
```

However, you can iterate over the column and access each URL individually, like so:

```
import pandas

data = pandas.read_excel("PATH/TO/XLSX")

for url in data.URL:
    print(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

This line assigns the URL column of the Dataframe to 'url':

```
url=data.URL
```

'url' is now a Pandas Series object and can be iterated through with a for loop:

```
for u in url:
    # your request here
```

See the Pandas documentation on Series for more info: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html

Note it might be easier to save the content of the text files located at the URLs locally and then afterwards search those saved files in order to avoid executing multiple requests for the same files.